# Trouble importing large amount of Data into MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Trying to import 350000 records of data from a csv into mysql workbench. After creating the tables and using table import wizard only about 18 rows of information are being transferred. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please publish table schema and first 20 rows of csv file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.